# propagate drop down with basename of images in current directory php

Tags: php, html

I've tried 2 different ways to tackle this as you can see here
none of them work. I have several jpg's in my directory and none of them work
Any help? I've tried literally everything to my code. I'm trying to make sure that it is accordance to phprules of organization where we don't use echo and such things.

```
<?php
    $images = glob("images/*.{jpeg,gif,png}", GLOB_BRACE);

    function drop($images)
    {?> 
        <select name="image"> 
        <?php
        foreach($images as $image)
        {?> 
            <option> <?php basename($image)?> </option> 
        <?php
        }?> 
        </select> <?php
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="order-submit.php" method="post">

            Food Item: <?=  drop($images);?>

            Food Item:

            <select name="food">
                  <option value="" selected="selected">-----</option>
              <?php 
                   foreach(glob(dirname(__FILE__) . '/images/*') as $filename){
                   $filename = basename($filename);
                   ?>
                   <option value= "<?= $filename ?>"> <?= $filename ?> </option> <?php
                }
            ?>
            </select> 

            <label for="Quantity">Quantity:</label>
            <input type="Text" name="Quantity" size="2"><br />

            <input type="Submit" value="Order" id="Submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You havent told us what doesnt work.  Does it error, does not have any <options>?  dump out your $images, does it have your files in there?

Comment: Yes. Nothing at all loads in the ddrop down :(

Answer (score 0):

I set up an images dir with img1.jpeg and img2.jpeg (make sure you don't have jpg, if you do at it to your {} in glob)

```
$images = glob("images/*.{jpeg,gif,png}", GLOB_BRACE);
var_dump($images);
```

shows:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(18) "./images/img1.jpeg"
  [1]=>
  string(18) "./images/img2.jpeg"
}
```

Your drop function doesn't return anything. So we create a string and return it in our function.

```
function drop($images) {
    $str = '<select name="image">';

    foreach($images as $image) {
        $str .= '<option>'. basename($image).'</option>';
    }
    $str .= '</select>';

    return $str;
}
```

now our images array is set, and our function is set to return, so we can call it, and print out the output:

```
$mySelectMenu = drop($images);

echo $mySelectMenu;
```

which prints out:

```
<select name="image"><option>img1.jpeg</option><option>img2.jpeg</option></select>
```

Comment: Yeah I tried that in it's pure form and it didn't work :*(

Comment: did you add the return? cause this works fine:
 <?php
    $images = array("img1", "img2", "img3"); 
    ?>

    <?= drop($images); ?>

Comment: var_dump($images); what does that array look like?